# try to install - iOS6.0.1 and air 3.5.0.880

Tags: ios, ios6, air, flash-cs6

okay let see if i can explain this right

I am trying to install a flash air application  on to a iOS6.0.1 device, i keep getting an error
"appID failed to install"

I am using flash professional CS6  modify a existing application and publishing with Air 3.5.0.880.
and iTunes to install

---

what i have tried!

1. Re-registered Devices
2. Recreated an AppID
3. Deleted mobile provisioning profiles on device
4. Recreated mobile provisioning profiles
5. Reinstalled mobile provisioning profiles on device

Answer (score 0):

try to update the certificate too

even revoke if needed!!

if you want a short .bat file (for windows)
for converting a .cer file to .p12 file.. respond and I'll give you

Good Luck

EDIT:

CHECK THAT YOU USES DEVELOPMENT CERTIFICATE AND DEVELOPMENT MOBILE PROVISION
DON'T USE THE DISTRIBUTION!!!